# Transparent highlight in XKCD plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparency

I would like to use some XKCD style plots on my blog. Here is an example figure:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with plt.xkcd():

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7))
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_ylim([-30, 15])
    # Plot of function
    x = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=100)
    y = x ** 3 - 10 * x
    ax.plot(x, y, color='y')
    # Tangent space
    ax.plot(x, 2 * x - 16, color='m')
    ax.text(3, -10, r'$T_pC$', color='m')
    ax.scatter(2, -12, color='m')
    ax.text(2, -12, r'$p$', color='m')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('/first_example_tangent_space.png', transparent=True, dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

The problem is it doesn't look good in dark mode, revealing white highlights:

Light mode:

[image]

Dark mode:

[image]

The highlights around the curves and text are fine, but the boxes are distracting. Is there a way to change the white highlights to transparent highlights for those boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the x-/y-axis at all? Unfortunately, it seems that you cannot completely hide the spines (`ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)`) using `savefig` with `transparent=True`.

`ax.axis('off')` will remove the whole box. Setting `bbox_inches='tight'`, you'll be able to adjust padding yourself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with plt.xkcd():

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7))
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_ylim([-30, 15])
    # Plot of function
    x = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=100)
    y = x ** 3 - 10 * x
    ax.plot(x, y, color='y')
    # Tangent space
    ax.plot(x, 2 * x - 16, color='m')
    ax.text(3, -10, r'$T_pC$', color='m')
    ax.scatter(2, -12, color='m')
    ax.text(2, -12, r'$p$', color='m')

    ax.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('./first_example_tangent_space.png', transparent=True, dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
```